# Convert from List of string array to List of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, list

If I have a simple class that looks like this:

```
public string Param1 { get; set; }
public string Param2 { get; set; }
public SimpleClass (string a, string b) { Param1 = a; Param2 = b; }
```

List of string array returned from another class:

```
var list = new List<string[]> {new[] {"first", "second"}, new[] {"third", "fourth"}};
```

Is there a more efficient way using C# to end up with `List<SimpleClass>` without doing something like:

```
var list1 = new List<SimpleClass>();
foreach (var i in list)
{          
    var data = new SimpleClass(i[0], i[1]);
    list1.Add(data);         
}
```

Comment: Could mean, not creating redundant variables inside `foreach`, or perhaps a standard library that does such things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Linq:

```
var simpleClassList = originalList.Select(x => new SimpleClass(x[0], x[1])).ToList()
```

Comment: Yes, or with the very old-fashioned `ConvertAll` instance method `var simpleClassList = originalList.ConvertAll(x => new SimpleClass(x[0], x[1]));` where a `List<>` is returned directly (so no lazy enumerator).

Answer (score 3):

As was said by @rualmar you can use linq. But you also can overload implicit operator. 
For example

```
public static implicit operator SimpleClass(string[] arr)
{
    return new SimpleClass(arr[0], arr[1]);
}
```

and after that you can write this

```
var list = new List<SimpleClass> { new[] { "first", "second" }, new[] { "third", "fourth" } };
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.