# Add string items from array to a list of object

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, arraylist

I have an array of string defined as follows:

```
string[] items = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"};
```

Then I have a model defined as :

```
public class ItemModel {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string ItemName { get; set; }

        public bool IsItem { get; set; }
}
```

I have defined a list as :

```
var listItems = new List<ItemModel>();
```

I want to add the items from the array `items` to the list of object of `listItems`. I want to add the items to `ItemName`

Comment: while adding to `List<ItemModel>` whats the `Id` and `IsItem` for respective item?

Comment: You want to set `ItemName` by some logic? or just randomly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert from List of string array to List of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118975/convert-from-list-of-string-array-to-list-of-objects)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved using a very simple Linq:

```
listItems  = items.Select(i => new ItemModel { ItemName = i}).ToList();
```

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118975/convert-from-list-of-string-array-to-list-of-objects

Comment: @JohnB is the question duplicate or the answer? ;)

Comment: @JohnB well then you should comment it on question

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Its recommended not to answer duplicates though. You have to make people search a bit (or direct them to the correct answer by marking as duplicate)

Comment: @EpicKip you are absolutely right, but when I saw the question, I didn't search it, I knew the answer, so I answered.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Yeah but because its such a simple question you kinda knew it was a dupe... But whatever, not going to argue.

Comment: it would be a very strange world if we not allowed to have duplicate answers!  saying `duplicate` always obviously infers `duplicate question`

Comment: @JohnB Its allowed but you'd be encouraging duplicate questions with duplicate answers (they always get their answer so they don't care they did not search enough).

Answer (score 2):

You could either use `Select` as:

```
  var result = items.Select(i => new ItemModel {ItemName = i}).ToList()
```

Or:

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
    listItems.Add(new ItemModel{ItemName = item});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    listItems = items.Select(i => new ItemModel { Id = Array.IndexOf(items, i), ItemName = i, IsItem = true }).ToList();
```